# How can i use feature weighting methods other than TF-IDF in weka?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, text-classification

1) I want to apply feature weighting methods like IG, MI to weight my features but StringToWordVector only allows us to use TF-IDf for weighting features in weka.

Is there a way with which i can apply weighting methods other than TF-IDF for weighting my terms ?

2) How can i access TF-IDF weight of each feature in java code ? I debugged the code and find out that all terms are assigned weight 1.0 ?

```
 filterInstances.attribute(i).weight() // filter instances is set of instances after applying tf-idf
```

3) Does terms with IG less than 0 does not help in classification process and we should always eliminate them from vocabulary ?

Thanx in advance ...